# NestJs instantiate class with dependencies

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I'm completely new to Nestjs moving from Laravel, really enjoying it, but it's kinda more difficult to find answers online.

I got a base class with a dependency of the HttpService:

```
export abstract class BaseClass {
    constructor(protected httpService: HttpService) {} 
}
```

I got a couple of classes extending the base class, and I'm trying to instantiate them on the fly:

```
const bus = new BusClass([
  new classNumber1(this.httpService),
  new classNumber2(this.httpService),
]);
```

I want to find a way to NOT pass the httpService to the constructors,
just like NestJs doing it when we inject services on the constructors in the controllers for example.

I tried with factories and really any example from the docs, with no success.

Will be glad for any kind of help, thanks allot ahead!

Comment: have you added the Injectable decorator in your service?

Comment: in which context this `bus` should be initiated? you can't use nestjs DI everywhere in the nodejs project.